# Is my understanding correct about egrep -if file1 file2?

Tags: grep

I am using KSH, Solaris 5.10.
Suppose `file1` contains a list of fruits and `file2` contains list of fruits & nuts.
My understanding about the following command

```
egrep -if file1 file2
```

is that it will take line 1 from `file1` and search for it in entire `file2` and it repeats this process for all lines in `file1`.

So final output will be all the fruits that are present in both `file1` and `file2`. Correct me if am wrong and suggest me any improvements if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal mechanism might be different, but yes, the effect is what you described. Caveats:

- The command as given will match lines in `file2`, if any part of it matches a line in `file1`. So `apple` in `file1` will match `pineapple` in `file2`. You can avoid this by using `-x` as well:

  ```
  -x    Consider  only  input  lines that use all characters in the line
        excluding the terminating <newline> to  match  an  entire  fixed
        string or regular expression to be matching lines.
  ```

  If you do use this, then I think you can skip `egrep` and use `grep` directly.
- An empty line in `file1` will cause *everything* in `file2` to be printed, so you should filter out such lines:

  ```
  grep -xif <(grep . file1) file2
  ```
- Depending on what your actual files contain, you might want to treat `file1` as a list of fixed strings instead of as extended regular expressions. An `pea.` might match `pear`. So do:

  ```
  grep -xiFf <(grep . file1) file2
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your suggesstions, i will make sure there will be no empty lines both files. In solaris 5.10, KSH neither grep nor egrep does't seem to be having the option of -x. i am stuck with egrep -if. In reality both my files will have 4 digit numbers, so there is no scenario of apple and pineapple. But very good point. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @ayrton_senna I was sure it was POSIX. Check if your Solaris has `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` - it might support `-x`. (Also, `ksh` is beside the point, `grep` and `egrep` are independent of it.)

Comment: Awesome, my solaris has `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`. i executed the command as `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -xif file1 file2`. worked like magic. Thank you. I get it, grep and egrep functionality depends on OS not the shell. Thanks

Comment: @mikeserv given a feature that cleanly expresses what I want to do, I tend to use it, that's all.

Comment: @mikeserv well, yes. The argument to `-f` is right where it's supposed to be. With `-`, I need to look back to the pipeline to be sure what it was. The more complex a command grows, the more I like to avoid mental gymnastics.

Comment: @mikeserv in fairness, when I see a question from a totally unfamiliar system (I had used Solaris 5.10 a few years ago), I tend to leave it for the likes of you, Gilles or Stephane. I'd probably be running around screaming if `-` isn't stdin.

Comment: @mikeserv I do too, my usual incantation is `grep -xFf`. I didn't because "fruits" suggested that OP probably wouldn't be using special characters.

Comment: Well, that is why I suggested it - because they seem to be doing `egrep` for whatever reason on patterns which seem like they shouldn't be patterns at all - and i suspect there is at least a little confusion about what matches and why. You've already got my vote, and i wont retract it, but also consider that this isn't *just* for asker either.

Comment: @mikeserv updated

Comment: Hey: `-iF` works! That's *cool*. I dunno why, but i guess just always assumed they were somehow mutually exclusive. Thanks, man.